# Limits: x Approaching Negative Infinity makes -x but why?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I came across this particular question on my maths textbook while I was revising for my exams.

[image: This is the question and the solution from the book publisher]

My solution for the question is 1, and Photomath said:

> $x$ is negative since $x$ approaches negative infinity

I can’t find any examples on the book that explains the problems, so now I am reaching out for help here for an explanation for this. Thanks!

P.S I have no idea of the code for displaying an equation, so both the question and the correct solution were uploaded as an image

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.   When $x<0$, $3x=-\sqrt{9x^2}$ -- does that help?

Comment: It is because $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$ then taking negative $x$ we have $\lvert x\rvert=-x$

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn MathJax, the "code for displaying an equation"

Comment: What is Photomath?

Comment: [Photomath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomath) is a free phone app that takes a picture of equations and solves them

Comment: For a non-negative real number $R$, the notation $\sqrt R$ means the non-negative number whose square is $R.$ So if $x<0$ then $\sqrt {9x^2}\,=|3x|=3|x|=3(-x)=-3x$..... Also if $A\ge 0$ and $B>0$ then $\frac {\sqrt A}{\sqrt B}=\sqrt {A/B}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is -1 since the numerator is positive (Since the leading term is $3|x|$) and the denominator approaches -$\infty$ which is negative and a positive divided by a negative is always negative even in the limit.